# Update Google Drive file download, print and copy option via Python Django Storage

Tags: python, django, google-drive-api

I want to update `DOWNLOAD, PRINT, COPY` option for google drive files using `django.core.files.storage`. While adding a file to drive with body parameter, I am able to update this option using following body parameter.

```
body = {
            'title': name,
            'mimeType': mime_type,
            'labels': {'restricted': True, 'hidden': True},
            'copyable': False,
            'writersCanShare': False
        }
```

How to update those options on a file which is already there in the drive. In the below image the last check box just above the **DONE** button is what we want to update.
[image]

#### UPDATE

while doing update permission right now I am passing following as body parameter:

```
private_permission = {
        'type': 'domain',
        'role': 'reader',
        'value': 'domian_name.com'
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it worked useing Updates file metadata and/or content API in Google Drive API [reference](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/update)

#### Sample Code:

```
body = {
            'labels': {'restricted': True}
        }
        self._drive_service.files().update(fileId=file_id,body=body).execute()
```